# What is this featureless Python exception?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.6

I have a script containing a section similar to this, on Python 2.6:

```
import sys

list_id='cow'
prev=[0,'cow']

try:
    if list_id==prev[1]:
        print '{0} is the same as {1}'.format(list_id,prev[1])
        sys.exit(0)
except:
    print 'exception occurred, exiting with error'
    sys.exit(1)
```

I noticed that though it was printing the 'is the same' line, it also logs the exception!

If you remove the try/except block, the interpreter shows no error. If you catch a specific error like ValueError, the except block is not executed.

```
import sys

list_id='cow'
prev=[0,'cow']

try:
    if list_id==prev[1]:
        print '{0} is the same as {1}'.format(list_id,prev[1])
        sys.exit(0)
except Exception as k:
    print 'exception occurred, exiting with error. Exception is:'
    print k.args
    sys.exit(1)
```

The except block is not executed, and the process finishes with return code 0. So, the exception is above Exception in the hierarchy?

```
import sys

list_id='cow'
prev=[0,'cow']

try:
    if list_id==prev[1]:
        print '{0} is the same as {1}'.format(list_id,prev[1])
        sys.exit(0)
except BaseException as k:
    print 'exception occurred, exiting with error. Exception is:'
    print k.args
    sys.exit(1)
```

produces

> cow is the same as cow exception occurred, exiting with error.
>   Exception is: (0,)

And the process finishes with exit code 1.

Why is this Except block being executed at all?

Comment: Printing repr(k) or type(k) is more informative in this case than k.args.

Comment: Thank you @Russell, that will surely help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) raises [`SystemExit`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SystemExit), which is what you're seeing.

As to why it doesn't inherit from `Exception`:

> The exception inherits from `BaseException` instead of `StandardError` or
>   `Exception` so that it is not accidentally caught by code that catches
>   `Exception`. This allows the exception to properly propagate up and cause the interpreter to exit.

Answer (score 3):

`sys.exit()` simply raises `SystemExit`.  That's how it exits the program.  When you catch all exceptions, you also catch `SystemExit`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other answers: SystemExit does not inherit from Exception, python exception hierarchy: http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html